# Deleting files in a cross platform compatible manner in .NET Core

Tags: c#, file-io, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to delete a file in a .NET Core 2.0 application but cannot find any alternative to File.Delete.

When creating or reading files we are encouraged to use providers as below because they wrap the underlying file system allowing cross platform access:

```
   IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(dir);
   IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(fileName);
```

However there does not appear to be any complimentary functionality for delete operations. System.IO is available in .NET Core 2.0 but is this cross platform compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this trivial app on Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace gbsills
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.Delete("file.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure you use the correct file path separators and such if you want to be cross-platform.

Comment: For some reason, I also ran into this problem and had to use System.IO.File.Delete() rather than the using statement along with just File.Delete(). Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or what, but the .NET Core 2.2 application doesn't seem to recognize File without System.IO.File.